# Why is man synonymized to manpage?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Correct me if I'm wrong but:

- I can ask for help writing a manpage
- I can ask about using the `man` command
- I can ask how to install specific manpages
- I can ask how to install man

These questions are different. Yeah, the tags are *"related"* but they are not **"the same thing"**, for any one. So why was this done? Could it be reverted back?

Comment: I think they are very closely related, so it's fine to synonym them(remember the "prefer existing tags" phrase in sidebar). But I also think it should have been done the other way round.